# Gunicorn workers terminated with signal 11 on docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to embed my Flask API in a Docker using a Gunicorn server. When I launch it locally it works just fine. However, when running on Docker all workers are terminated with signal 11 without further information. I tried to increase `--timeout` but it is not working either. I am using `gevent` workers. Do you have any clue of what could be happening? I append the debug trace from my execution.

My environment is using Python 3.6.

```
gunicorn \
 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 \
 --access-logfile=${LOGFILE} \
 --workers 1 \
 --worker-class gevent \
 --timeout 1000 \
 --log-level debug \ 
 --capture-output wsgi:app
```

```
[2021-10-11 09:02:31 +0000] [8] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  config: ./gunicorn.conf.py
  wsgi_app: None
  bind: ['0.0.0.0:5000']
  backlog: 2048
  workers: 1
  worker_class: gevent
  worker_connections: 1000
  max_requests: 0
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  timeout: 1000
  graceful_timeout: 30
  keepalive: 2
  limit_request_line: 4094
  limit_request_fields: 100
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  reload: False
  reload_engine: auto
  reload_extra_files: []
  spew: False
  check_config: False
  print_config: False
  preload_app: False
  sendfile: None
  reuse_port: False
  chdir: ${PROJECT_PATH}
  daemon: False
  raw_env: []
  pidfile: None
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  user: 0
  group: 0
  umask: 0
  initgroups: False
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  accesslog: ${LOGFILE}
  disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  errorlog: ${LOGFILE}
  loglevel: debug
  capture_output: True
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  logconfig: None
  logconfig_dict: {}
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog: False
  syslog_prefix: None
  syslog_facility: user
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  statsd_host: None
  dogstatsd_tags: 
  statsd_prefix: 
  proc_name: None
  default_proc_name: wsgi:app
  pythonpath: None
  paste: None
  on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7f32384b7280>
  on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7f32384b73a0>
  when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7f32384b74c0>
  pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7f32384b75e0>
  post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7f32384b7700>
  post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7f32384b7820>
  worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7f32384b7940>
  worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7f32384b7a60>
  pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7f32384b7b80>
  pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7f32384b7ca0>
  post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7f32384b7d30>
  child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7f32384b7e50>
  worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7f32384b7f70>
  nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7f32380bd0d0>
  on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7f32380bd1f0>
  proxy_protocol: False
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  keyfile: None
  certfile: None
  ssl_version: 2
  cert_reqs: 0
  ca_certs: None
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  ciphers: None
  raw_paste_global_conf: []
  strip_header_spaces: False
```

The error log file looks like this:

```
[2021-10-11 08:46:34 +0000] [9] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-10-11 08:46:34 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2021-10-11 08:46:34 +0000] [9] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (9)
[2021-10-11 08:46:34 +0000] [9] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
[2021-10-11 08:46:34 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2021-10-11 08:46:34 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] 1 workers
[2021-10-11 08:46:35 +0000] [9] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 11
[2021-10-11 08:46:35 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
[2021-10-11 08:46:35 +0000] [9] [WARNING] Worker with pid 11 was terminated due to signal 11
[2021-10-11 08:46:35 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
[2021-10-11 08:46:35 +0000] [9] [WARNING] Worker with pid 12 was terminated due to signal 11
[2021-10-11 08:46:35 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
[2021-10-11 08:46:35 +0000] [9] [WARNING] Worker with pid 13 was terminated due to signal 11
...
```

Comment: Signal 11 is SIGSEGV. Your workers are just crashing – how have you e.g. installed dependencies in the image? How are you launching the container?

Comment: @AKX I have setup the same environment using CONDA on my Docker. I execute using the following command: `docker run [ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES] -d -p 5000:5000 expai:latest`. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I don't know what else to tell you than that your workers are crashing with a SIGSEGV. Are they maybe missing some data file and some native code isn't equipped to handle that?

Comment: @AKX I will try to figure it out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello! any updates here?

Comment: Any updates here?